# Is there a Google play store apk available somewhere?

Tags: google-play-store, root-access, apk

Everyone keeps telling me that such apk has never been published by Google. Is that so?

I need to put Google Play Store on a Chinese mobile, but I cant root nor flash it with a custom recovery ROM. I wanted to use the Open Gapps zip but all of those require custom recovery. Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think they are wrong, since the .apk file are found on various apk hosting sites. You can grab one from [APKmirror](https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-store/), and can always update it once it is installed.